# XML::FeedPP and accessing media:* property

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a youtube xml feed and want to access certain **media** elements in the feed.

I'm able to access basic elements such as *title* and *link* but accessing anything under **media:group** returns empty string.

[image]

```
use XML::FeedPP; 
my $feed = XML::FeedPP->new("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml\?channel_id\=UCzJuUAme9EABE1quatA8z-Q"); 

foreach my $item ( $feed->get_item() ) { 
    print $item->get("media:group") . "\n";
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can access the *media:group* and its child elements ?

Comment: You don't need to escape the `?` or `=` with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks. I was copy/pasting from the shell which seems to have escaped those automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the `$item` objects in that feed with Data::Printer shows that the objects know about the `media:group` and other things in the `media:` namespace.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use XML::FeedPP;
my $feed = XML::FeedPP->new("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCzJuUAme9EABE1quatA8z-Q");

foreach my $item ( $feed->get_item() ) {
    p $item;
}

__END__
XML::FeedPP::Atom::Atom10::Entry  {
    Parents       XML::FeedPP::Atom::Common::Entry
    public methods (6) : category, description, get_pubDate_native, link, pubDate, title
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        author         {
            name   "Fun to Origami",
            uri    "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzJuUAme9EABE1quatA8z-Q"
        },
        id             "yt:video:332UeGpfY3E",
        link           {
            -href   "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=332UeGpfY3E",
            -rel    "alternate"
        },
        media:group    {
            media:community     {
                media:starRating   {
                    -average   4.56,
                    -count     9,
                    -max       5,
                    -min       1
                },
                media:statistics   {
                    -views   940
                }
            },
            media:content       {
                -height   390,
                -type     "application/x-shockwave-flash",
                -url      "https://www.youtube.com/v/332UeGpfY3E?version=3",
                -width    640
            },
            media:description   "...",
            media:thumbnail     {
                -height   360,
                -url      "https://i4.ytimg.com/vi/332UeGpfY3E/hqdefault.jpg",
                -width    480
            },
            media:title         "Origami Pteranodon : Paper Dinosaur Tutorial"
        },
        published      "2015-02-20T01:22:36+00:00",
        title          "Origami Pteranodon : Paper Dinosaur Tutorial",
        updated        "2016-02-15T13:42:07+00:00",
        yt:channelId   "UCzJuUAme9EABE1quatA8z-Q",
        yt:videoId     "332UeGpfY3E"
    }
}
```

<sup>Source: Youtube, Omission mine</sup>

So the most obvious way would be to just access the data structure directly. Of course **you don't want to do that**, as it's bad style, and **the underlying implementation might change**.

```
foreach my $item ( $feed->get_item() ) {
    say $item->{'media:group'}->{'media:content'}->{'-height'};
}

__END__
390
...
```

If this is a run-once-and-forget script, stop here.

---

Now the fun part begins. The `$item` is an [XML::FeedPP::Atom::Atom10::Entry](https://metacpan.org/source/KAWASAKI/XML-FeedPP-0.43/lib/XML/FeedPP.pm#L1956), which is an [XML::FeedPP::Item](https://metacpan.org/source/KAWASAKI/XML-FeedPP-0.43/lib/XML/FeedPP.pm#L830), which is an [XML::FeedPP::Element](https://metacpan.org/source/KAWASAKI/XML-FeedPP-0.43/lib/XML/FeedPP.pm#L2164). That guy [has a method `get`](https://metacpan.org/source/KAWASAKI/XML-FeedPP-0.43/lib/XML/FeedPP.pm#L2239). It looks like it would not have a problem dealing with the `:` part, but it returns `undef.`

This module seems to be extensively tested. There is an [11_media.t](https://metacpan.org/source/KAWASAKI/XML-FeedPP-0.43/t/11_media.t) that actually plays around with the `media:` namespace. In the examples there, however, it not only probably work (or I could not have installed the module), but it's also a bit different. The `media:` element is not very deep. It's just one tag with attributes.

Feel free to take the research further from this point.

Comment: You are right accessing the elements via the `hash` is the way to go. I did look at the underlying class and it seems to internally pass a namespace object and I suspect the namespace provided by youtube is the issue here.